# How to include () in query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-entities

iam have two modal i I'm trying to include all ***Post*** that belong the User. However, I keep getting the following debug error:
Error   58  Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

please see pic [image][image]

```
 public IList<User> GetSliderImages()
    {
        var q = db.Users.Include(x=>x.Post).OrderByDescending(x => x.FPersonalUser).Where(x => x.typemanger == 1).ToList();
        return q;

    }
 public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_User { set; get; }
    public Int16 ID_post { set; get; }   
    public bool Fbofd { set; get; } 
    public string FuserName { set; get; }
    public bool Foffice { set; get; }
    public byte[] FPicaddress { set; get; }
    **public IList<Post> _post { set; get; }**
}

   public partial class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int ID_Post { set; get; }
    public string FNamePost { set; get; }

}
```

Comment: Have up included `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: dude #Stephen Muecke ,he not use relationship between two table so this type of error occurred here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public virtual ICollection<Post> Post{ get; set; }
```

please use look like this for using relationship between two table then use include syntax.

Comment: iam replace   public IList<Post> _post { set; get; }  to public virtual ICollection<Post> Post{ get; set; }  but  following debug error: Error 58 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: can you paste screen shot here?

Comment: where you have raise the bug?

Comment: fisrt image before complie secend  image after complie .i wnat show fnamepost but see error why see this error Error 8 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: `public class User` should be  `public partial class User`. can you try this? #amir1364

Comment: iam sloved iam use using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;  iam change with using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: because depend on issues.